# Facebook Marketing API issue: (#10) Application does not have permission for this action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to access Instagram Ad comments using Facebook Marketing API. But When I try the following command:

```
curl -G \
-d "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>"\
-d "fields=id,message,instagram_user"\
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<EFFECTIVE_INSTAGRAM_STORY_ID>/comments"
```

I receive this error:

```
{'error': {'message': '(#10) Application does not have permission for this action', 'fbtrace_id': '', 'code': 10, 'type': 'OAuthException'}}
```

I am able to get the ads, their creatives but not the comments.

I used to be able to do the same a few months back. I am not sure what has changed. I do the same with Python but it is same as curl so in case someone do need to see it I can share it.

Here are the permissions that my app requests(it has development access and I am admin of both the ad account and the app):

```
Permissions
email
ads_read
ads_management
business_management
instagram_manage_comments
```

Comment: You solve this? If so, how?

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: I don't remember but it got fixed after sometime without any change on my end so maybe it was some issue with Facebook. But first of all please check that you have all the permissions and suitable role in Facebook development console.